# is there a way for object detection or recognition with 2d laser scanner?

Tags: slam, navigation, laser, sicklms, scanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have lms100 laser scanner and i want to do any kind of object or obstacle detection/recognition. Is there anyway to do that with help of ROS?

By the way, currently I can create map with hector_slam with LMS100.

edit: i think costmap can show obstacles. but i'm not sure, it can apply to my situtation (having only laser scanner not a robot system)

Thanks, Basak

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235006/is-there-a-way-for-object-detection-or-recognition-with-2d-laser-scanner-?/) by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a package for your scanner within ROS from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/LMS1xx)

Then you can look for available source code, [problems/solutions](http://answers.ros.org/question/11074/sick-lms-100-topic-stops-publishing-measurements/).. etc

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2016-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-05-23**:
I am using that LMS1xx driver package for hector_slam already. But didnt understand your answer

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-05-23**:
I didn't know that you already have a package, so my answer was about that package and the second link is about a problem related to your scanner, from it you can get some information

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-07**:
so your answer is not an answer for my question :/ Do you know what should i do for obstacle detection, avoidance?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-06-07**:
Sorry I didn't work with this sensor before, but I would recommend you to use the hashtag #hector_slam:
http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/tags:hector_slam/page:1/
And check what people asking about and what they do..etc